# What's is the meaning of "to" in this context—"Trace to"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, definition

**Hev was traced "to" an address in Tacoma.**

I could not find any relevant definition for this.

Comment: See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trace

Comment: Do you know what "trace" means? Where did you research meanings of "to"? Because some of these [in Merriam-Webster "to"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) seem relevant e.g. "to indicate contact or proximity". You don't give much information on the problem you're having.

Comment: This has been proposed for reopening but I see no edits. Please use the Edit button to show what you found (or didn't!). I know it's hard to show that you *didn't* find a relevant definition of "to," but I think you found it and didn't realize it, so please paste what you found. Also, note the advice to look up "trace" instead of "to." Finally, try to say more about your confusion so there can be better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace in this context means to follow a trail of leads. In this case, the trail led **to** an address in Tacoma.

Check out the last example in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trace):

> Their missing daughter was finally traced to (= found in) Manchester